# Xpath selecting text() preceding br based on previous sibling text

Tags: html, xpath, siblings

I have this HTML code:

```
<td width="220" align="left">
    <b>Valor da Venda:</b> 
    R$ 650.000,00<br>
    <b>Valor do IPTU:</b> 
    R$ 0,00<br>
    <b>Valor do Condomínio:</b> 
    R$ 0,00
</td>
```

I'm  trying to select the text() from preceding "br" tags where the text() in the preceding "b" tag is equal to "Valor da Venda:".

I tried with:

```
/td//text()[preceding::br and contains(../b/text(),'Valor da Venda:')]
```

But this is returning

```
[' R$ 650.000,00', ' R$ 0,00', ' R$ 0,00 ']
```

while i wanted to return only the first one R$ 650.000,00

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly as asked, might this be a solution for you?

```
/td/b[.="Valor da Venda:"]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Or, if the `br`needs to be checked:

```
/td/b[.="Valor da Venda:"]/following-sibling::text()[1][following-sibling::br]'
```

Comment: For some reason the /br is not interpreted as sibling of the tag b. Dont know why, either of your solutions (that seems correct to me) are working for lxml xpath interpreter =(

Comment: I think maybe it's because br is not closed.

Comment: Depens on what you are using I guess, this works in PHP DOM if I load it as HTML. If I load it as XML, if fails of course, because this is ***NOT*** XML. What _are_ you using?